# How to bind property to ChipBackground of SfChipGroup?

Tags: maui, syncfusion

I use a SfChipGroup and I bind as ItemSource a *PageButtonList* from my ViewModel.

```cs
private ObservableCollection<PageModel> _pageButtonList = new ObservableCollection<PageModel>();

public ObservableCollection<PageModel> PageButtonList
{
    get { return _pageButtonList; }
    set
    {
        _pageButtonList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PageButtonList");
    }
}
```

For the background color I will use a boolean property from the *PageButtonList* object *IsCurrentPage*.
That for I use a *BoolToColorConverter*.

```xml
<toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" 
                       TrueObject="{x:Static Colors.Red}"
                       FalseObject="{x:Static Colors.White}"/>
```

And use it like that:

```xml
<syncfusion:SfChipGroup ItemsSource="{Binding PageButtonList}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                        ChipBackground="{Binding IsCurrentPage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"
                        ChipTextColor="Black"/>
```

The list object class *PageModel* looks like that:

```cs
public class PageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title => (Id + 1).ToString();

    public bool IsCurrentPage { get; set; }

    public PageModel(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        IsCurrentPage = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is I get this error:

> Binding: Property "IsCurrentPage" not found on "MyApp.ViewModels.MyPageViewModel".

The Property *IsCurrentPage* belongs to the object *PageButtonList* which is part of *MyPageViewModel*. The error message is right, but **how can I tell the SfChipGroup the DataType is *PageModel*?**

Comment: use a [DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings) attribute on the `DataTemplate`

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible like that. You cannot set the `ChipBackground` property of the `SfChipGroup` based on the `IsCurrentPage` value of a single element inside the collection that serves as the `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible like that. You will need to provide a *DataTemplate* to the `SfChipGroup.ItemTemplate` instead, but this also means that you will have to fully configure the `SfChip` yourself inside that template:

```xml
<syncfusion:SfChipGroup ItemsSource="{Binding PageButtonList}">
    <syncfusion:SfChipGroup.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:PageModel">
            <syncfusion:SfChip
                Text="{Binding Title}"
                TextColor="Black"
                Background="{Binding IsCurrentPage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </syncfusion:SfChipGroup.ItemTemplate>
</syncfusion:SfChipGroup>
```